# Angular multiple template cycle

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

So I use a ng-if to cycle through the use of 6 different templates which each contain approx. 12 lines of html code. These are all in one view (including the templates in self contained  tags). In the controller for this page, among a few other functions, I dumped my app.factory and the varying directives for the templates in that controller. That code looks like:

```
app.directive('card', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '=ngModel'
        }
    };
});

app.directive('template1', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template1
    };
});

app.directive('template2', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template2
    };
});

app.directive('template3', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template3
    };
});

app.directive('template4', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template4
    };
});

app.directive('template5', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template5
    };
});

app.directive('template6', function (templates) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: templates.template6
    };
});

app.factory('templates', function () {
    return {
        template1: '<ng-include src="\'template1.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template2: '<ng-include src="\'template2.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template3: '<ng-include src="\'template3.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template4: '<ng-include src="\'template4.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template5: '<ng-include src="\'template5.html\'"></ng-include>',
        template6: '<ng-include src="\'template6.html\'"></ng-include>'        
    };
});
```

So my main question here is, is there a code way to consolidate this code? I had read some similar post, but they didn't give me quite was I was after. Seems somewhat repetitive the way it is now.

Additionally, as I mentioned, my templates are each about 12-15 lines of code times 6. For such small templates, is this best way to approach with angular in a view with less than 500 lines of code or should they be broken out into a single or multiple partials? They won't be used in any other view at this point.

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Splitting your code into components is good. But they should have meaningful names.

Comment: many ng-include will make slow in my experience, btw

Comment: Good points. Anyone show how it could be combined or improved?